# Using Boost Graph Library (BGL) in Fortran program

Tags: c++, boost, fortran, hybrid

Is there anyway, I can use the graph data structure using the Boost Graph Library (BGL) inside my FORTRAN program.

Could anyone help me or give me a hint. I want to do parallel graph structure on several processors in my MPI-FORTRAN code. Is it possible to use Boost Graph Library (BGL) for this purpose!

Kind regards,
Ziv

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would have to construct an intermediate layer, written in C++, that does all the templating in some special case useful for you and then call it from Fortran. `bind(C)` and `iso_c_binding` module are your friends. I successfully use Boost based library CGAL in Fortran using this approach.

Something along the lines of:

my_bgl.cc:

```
  #include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
  #include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

  using namespace boost;
extern "C"{  
  void* make_graph(int num_vertices, int num_edges, int *edge_array)
  {

    // create a typedef for the Graph type
    typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS> Graph;

    Graph *g = new Graph(num_vertices);

    // add the edges to the graph object
    for (int i = 0; i < num_edges; ++i)
      add_edge(edge_array[2*i], edge_array[2*i+1], *g);

    return g;
  }
}
```

my_bgl.f90:

```
module my_bgl
  use iso_c_binding

  interface
    type(c_ptr) function make_graph(num_vertices, num_edges, edge_array) bind(C,name="make_graph")
      import
      integer(c_int), value :: num_vertices
      integer(c_int), value :: num_edges
      integer(c_int) :: edge_array(2, num_edges)
    end function
  end interface

end module
```

The function `make_graph` returns an opaque pointer to a Graph from the points entered.

Comment: would you kindly help me and give me some examples how you are doing this. I really need some help in this regard.

Comment: See the edit for an example for start. (I used an example code from the BGL tutorial.)

Comment: Just a last comment, If you insist on Fortran 90 (but I suppose you mean 95) and cannot use Fortran 2003, you can keep the C++ part almost the same, but you would have to use the old and non-portable ways of calling C from Fortran. But it is also doable.

Comment: No, I do not insist on using FORTRAN 95, actually I am using FORTRAN 2003. In this case is there anything else I should know. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

No, boost is a C++ template library. Unless you port the code to FORTRAN, this is impossible.

Comment: Why? Fortran and C/C++ object modules can be compiled correctly to executable by gcc or Intel compiler.

Comment: C++ templates are not directly compiled to executable code, templates are preprocessed header-only code that is used in code generation. Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(C%2B%2B)

Comment: Of course you can compile template code to executable code, it will just be limited to the code for the objects you actually created.  ;-)